# Solve $2\cdot \sin x \cdot \sin (50°+2x)=\sin (50°)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find a solution for the problem:

$$2\cdot\sin x \cdot \sin (50°+2x)=\sin (50°), \quad x\in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

**Approach:**

I can check, by inspection, that $x=50°$ is a solution. I have tried open $\sin(50º+2x)$ but it didn't work. I also tried sum product relation but I got nothing interesting. Any hint?

P.S: I'm trying to solve using standard approach because the problem is in a high school level. That means I'm not using calculus.

Comment: What other trig properties have you learned in class?

Comment: Hi @Michael, I'm not a student. You can use anything, except calculus.

Comment: It has two solutions in given range, second one is $x\approx 22.62°$.

Comment: Ok, but can you show that?

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento You can see that from a plot [like here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2*sin(x)*sin(Pi%2F180*50%2B2*x)-sin(Pi%2F180*50)+for+x+from+0+to+pi%2F2). If you ask whether i can solve it exactly, i cannot, yet :).

Comment: Thank you @Sil. I'm also still trying.

Comment: i have found two solutions in radians, using the addition formulas

Comment: @Sonnhard: Could you please post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using Prosthaphaeresis Formula
$$
\sin(10°)+\sin(50°)=2\sin(30°)\cos(20°)=\cos(20°)
$$
Hence, we can see that :
$$
\sin(50°)=\cos(20°)-\sin(10°) \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Manipulating \eqref{1} :

We know that $\cos(180°+\theta)=-\cos(\theta)$. Hence, $\cos(20°)=-\cos(200°)$.

We know that $\cos(90°+\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$. Hence, $\sin(10°)=-\cos(100°)$

Substituting the values, we get :
$$
\sin(50°)=\cos(100°)-\cos(200°)
$$
According to Prosthaphaeresis Formula (Reverse Application):
$$
2\sin(A)\sin(B)=\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)
\\
\implies 2\sin(x)\sin(50°+2x)=\cos(50°+x)-\cos(50°+3x)
$$

Since :
$$
2\cdot\sin x \cdot \sin (50°+2x)=\sin (50°)
\\
\implies \cos(50°+x)-\cos(50°+3x)=\sin (50°)=\cos(100°)-\cos(200°)
\\
\implies \cos(50°+x)-\cos(50°+3x)=\cos(100°)-\cos(200°)
$$
Hence, we can see that $x=50°$ is an obvious solution. I think the second solution can also be figured out similarly although I don't think it will be as easy.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I think you have to work a bit more your answer. There isn't a way to find $x=50$ without guessing.

Comment: $50°$ is equal to $5*\pi/18$, but this is not a root.

Comment: @Math-fun, $2\sin 50º\cdot \sin150°=\sin 50°$, so $x=50°$ is a root.

Comment: @Arnaldo my bad, you are right!